# Has anyone got an espresso test to run both on-device and off-device (using Robolectric as Android Simulator)

Tags: android, robolectric

At I/O 2018, Google announced support for Robolectric as an Android Simulator.  They said you could write an espresso test case and run it either on a real device or Android emulator, OR on Robolectric running as an Android Simulator.

Has anyone got this working or do we need to wait for a future release of Robolectric?

I can't quite see how to get this working.

- Do I put my espresso test code in app/src/test or app/src/androidTest?
- I want my CI build to run my test code against Robolectric as the Android Simulator, but the same test code to run against my phone when I'm running it myself on my laptop.

Can anyone point me at a sample project that does this?

Comment: Do you have any update on this ?

Comment: One way you could do this is by looking at using sourceSets or some form of modulisation for intergrationTests and point to those files based on where the tests are running. So for example put all your tests that run roboelectric/espresso in a directory and add them as srcDirs to either `test` or `androidTest` based on environment